# sharing gmpy2 multi-precision integer between processes without copying

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gmpy

Is it possible to share gmpy2 multiprecision integers (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) between processes (created by multiprocessing) without creating copies in memory?
Each integer has about 750,000 bits. The integers are not modified by the processes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Tested code is below.**

I would try the following untested approach:

Create a memory mapped file using Python's `mmap` library.

Use `gmpy2.to_binary()` to convert a `gmpy2.mpz` instance into binary string.

Write both the length of the binary string and binary string itself into the memory mapped file. To allow for random access, you should begin every write at a multiple of a fixed value, say 94000 in your case.

Populate the memory mapped file with all your values.

Then in each process, use `gmpy2.from_binary()` to read the data from the memory mapped file.

You need to read both the length of the binary string and binary string itself. You should be able to pass a slice from the memory mapped file directly to `gmpy2.from_binary()`.

I may be simpler to create a list of `(start, end)` values for the position of each byte string in the memory mapped file and then pass that list to each process.

**Update: Here is some sample code that has been tested on Linux with Python 3.4.**

```
import mmap
import struct
import multiprocessing as mp
import gmpy2

# Number of mpz integers to place in the memory buffer.
z_count = 40000
# Maximum number of bits in each integer.
z_bits = 750000
# Total number of bytes used to store each integer.
# Size is rounded up to a multiple of 4.
z_size = 4 + (((z_bits + 31) // 32) * 4)

def f(instance):
    global mm

    s = 0
    for i in range(z_count):
        mm.seek(i * z_size)
        t = struct.unpack('i', mm.read(4))[0]
        z = gmpy2.from_binary(mm.read(t))
        s += z
    print(instance, z % 123456789)

def main():
    global mm

    mm = mmap.mmap(-1, z_count * z_size)
    rs = gmpy2.random_state(42)
    for i in range(z_count):
        z = gmpy2.mpz_urandomb(rs, z_bits)
        b = gmpy2.to_binary(z)
        mm.seek(i * z_size)
        mm.write(struct.pack('i', len(b)))
        mm.write(b)

    ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    pool = ctx.Pool(4)
    pool.map_async(f, range(4))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: let me try it and get the timing. I just tried multiprocessing manager. That one seems slow.

Comment: that from_binary function is slow. is it possible to treat the whole mmap as a single xmpz. Then, at start of each process, the whole mmap is interpreted as a single xmpz without copying the contents of the mmap. After that,we can perform operations on the slices of the xmpz.

Comment: The current implementation of to_binary()/from_binary() is intended to be platform neutral. The trade-off is performance. I've been thinking about faster versions but it probably will take some time before I can work on it.

Comment: I use a global list of mpz in the end. It seems that the processes only copy the memory page containing the reference count instead of copying the mpz. The code was run with python 2.7.11.